# Prometheus: Get CPU Usage % for one specific process from windows_exporter

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to develop one query to show **the CPU Usage(%)** for **one specific process** in one **windows server**.
After digging into the metrics of windows exporter, I found [Metric: process.windows_process_cpu_time_total](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.process.md#metrics) should be the one.

I tried several queries, But all of them are not correct.

One of the Queries I tried:

`100 * sum(windows_process_cpu_time_total{job="xxxx", process="Idle"})/(sum(windows_process_cpu_time_total{job="xxxx"}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I made it.

Below query seems match the actual usage.

`100 * sum by (instance) (irate(windows_process_cpu_time_total{job="xxxx", process="Idle"}[1m]))/sum by (instance) (irate(windows_process_cpu_time_total{job="xxxx"}[1m]))`